How to fix Python version conflict due to multiple installations on Windows?
I recently updated Python on my Windows system from version 3.11.8 to 3.13.1. However, after completing the installation, my system continues to use the old Python version (3.11.8) instead of the newly installed version (3.13.1).
I’ve tried running the python --version command in the Command Prompt, but it still shows Python 3.11.8 even after I installed the latest version. Here's what I found so far:
Multiple Python Installations: I checked which Python installations exist on my system by running the following command:
bash: "where python"

The output showed:
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe

It seems that the older version of Python (3.11.8) is located in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ while the new version is located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\.
PATH Variable: I opened the Environment Variables and checked the PATH variable. I discovered that the path to the older Python version C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ is listed above the path to the new Python installation C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\.
To resolve the issue, I reordered the paths in the Environment Variables to prioritize the newer Python version. After saving the changes, I restarted the Command Prompt and ran python --version again, but the old version still showed up.
I am unable to set Python 3.13.1 as the default version and can't seem to resolve the conflict between the two installations.

You should try by removing the older python version from environment variable PATH.
